# How to pass data from a page to another page using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Please I need help on react-router-dom, I am new to the library and can seem to find any solution since. I am getting three results from an api call, in which I map over the data to render it on UI, now what I need now is that if I click on a row on one of this list, I want it to take me to a screen showing the details of only that single thing I clicked on.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class User extends Component {
  state = { userDetails: "" };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://urlforapi.com`)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      this.setState({
        userDetails: data
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { userDetails } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {userDetails
          ? userDetails.map(info => {
              return (
                <Link to="/home/userDetails">
                  <div key={info.id}>
                    <p>{info.name}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>{info.age}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>{info.description}</p>
                  </div>
                </Link>
              );
            })
          : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 32):

## Option 1: Pass Route State

Send the state in the route transition.

- Using `react-router-dom` v6

  Declarative Navigation - [Link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link) or [Navigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) components

  The link API changed a bit in v6, the `state` is now a prop.

  ```
  <Link
    to='/home/userDetails'
    state={{ infoId: info.id }}
  >
  ```

  or using the `Navigate` component, the spiritual successor/replacement to the v5 `Redirect` component

  ```
  <Navigate
    to="/home/userDetails"
    state={{ infoId: info.id }}
  />
  ```

  Imperative Navigation - [useNavigate hook](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)

  ```
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  navigate('/home/userDetails', { state: { infoId: info.id } });
  ```

  You can then unpack the state from the `location` object on the component being returned by that route. Use guards in case a user has navigated to `'/home/userDetails'` from elsewhere, as `state` may be undefined.

  ```
  const { state: { infoId } = {} } = useLocation();
  ```

  [image: Edit how-to-pass-data-from-a-page-to-another-page-using-react-router (forked)]
- Using `react-router-dom` v5

  Declarative Navigation - [Link to](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object)

  You can pass some state unique to the mapped entry, like `info.id` along with the route push that happens when the link is clicked. This obfuscates the data from the user as you aren't leaking information out to the ui (i.e. the browser).

  ```
  <Link
    to={{
      pathname: '/home/userDetails',
      state: { infoId: info.id },
    }}
  >
  ```

  Imperative Navigation - [useHistory hook](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

  ```
  const history = useHistory();

  ...

  history.push({
    pathname: '/home/userDetails',
    state: { infoId: info.id },
  });
  ```

  You can then unpack the state from the `location` prop/object on the component being returned by that route. Use guards in case a user has navigated to `'/home/userDetails'` from elsewhere, as `state` may be undefined.

  If passed route props:

  ```
  props.location && props.location.state && props.location.state.infoId
  ```

  or

  ```
  props.location?.state?.infoId
  ```

  If using function components then you can also use the `useLocation` React hook:

  ```
  const { state: { infoId } = {} } = useLocation();
  ```

  [image: Edit lucid-kowalevski-uxgs4]

## Option 2: Pass Something in the URL path

```
<Link to={`/home/userDetails/${info.id}`>
```

or (RRDv6)

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

...

navigate(`/home/userDetails/${info.id}`);
```

or (RRDv5)

```
const history = useHistory();

...

history.push(`/home/userDetails/${info.id}`);
```

And retrieve the param from the `match` prop in the returned route component. For example if the route looks like this:

- Using `react-router-dom` v6

  ```
  <Route path="/home/userDetails/:infoId" element={<Detail />} />
  ```

  There is only the `useParams` hook in v6, there are no route props.

  ```
  const { infoId } = useParams();
  ```

The user can see this, but you don't have to use the guard pattern to access since by definitions it'll be defined by the route (though `infoID` can still be defined if the user types in an invalid id).

- Using `react-router-dom` v5

  ```
  <Route path="/home/userDetails/:infoId" component={Detail} />
  ```

  Then in the component get id from the `match` route prop:

  ```
  props.match.params.infoId
  ```

  And in the case of function components, the `useParams` React hook:

  ```
  const { infoId } = useParams();
  ```

## Option 3: Pass Something in the URL queryString

- Using `react-router-dom` v6

  Declarative Navigation - [Link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link) or [Navigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) components

  The link API changed a bit in v6, the `state` is now a prop.

  ```
  <Link
    to={{
      pathname: '/home/userDetails',
      search: `?infoId=${info.id}`,
    }}
  >
  ```

  or using the `Navigate` component, the spiritual successor/replacement to the v5 `Redirect` component

  ```
  <Navigate
    to={{
      pathname: '/home/userDetails',
      search: `?infoId=${info.id}`,
    }}
  />
  ```

  Imperative Navigation - [useNavigate hook](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)

  ```
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  navigate({
    pathname: '/home/userDetails',
    search: `?infoId=${info.id}`,
  });
  ```

  You can then unpack the `infoId` query param from the `useSearchParams` hook.

  ```
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const infoId = searchParams.get("infoId");
  ```

  New in v6.4.0 is the [createSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/create-search-params) utility function.

  ```
  <Link
    to={{
      pathname: '/home/userDetails',
      search: createSearchParams({ infoId: info.id}),
    }}
  >
  ```

  or

  ```
  navigate({
    pathname: '/home/userDetails',
    search: createSearchParams({ infoId: info.id}),
  });
  ```
- Using `react-router-dom` v5

  Declarative Navigation - [Link to](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object)

  ```
  <Link
    to={{
      pathname: '/home/userDetails',
      search: `?infoId=${info.id}`,
    }}
  >
  ```

  Imperative Navigation - [useNavigate hook](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)

  ```
  const history = useHistory();

  ...

  history.push({
    pathname: '/home/userDetails',
    search: `?infoId=${info.id}`,
  });
  ```

  You can then unpack the `infoId` query param from the `location` prop/object on the component being returned by that route.

  If passed route props:

  `props.location && props.location.search`

  or

  `props.location?.search`

  If using function components then you can also use the `useLocation` React hook:

  `const { search } = useLocation();`

  Then create a URLSearchParams object and access the `infoId` parameter.

  ```
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
  const infoId = searchParams.get("infoId");
  ```

## But I'm using a React class component

In `react-router-dom@6` the route props and `withRouter` HOC were removed. To access the old "route props" in RRDv6 you'll need to create your own `withRouter` HOC replacement that can use the React hooks and inject props that can be used in React class components.

```
import { useLocation, useParams, /* other hooks */ } from 'react-router-dom'; 

const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const params = useParams();
  // other hooks

  return (
    <WrappedComponent
      {...props}
      {...{ location, params, /* other hooks */ }}
    />
  );
};
```

Decorate the component and access props:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...

  this.props.location.state;
  this.props.params;
  ...etc...

  ...
};

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

## References

- [location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location)
- [match](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)
- [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) v5
- [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location) v6
- [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) v5
- [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) v6
- [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) v6.4.0

Comment: I don't seem to understand the first option, can you please show some code on how to get this data on that second page. I tried it and it keeps returning "undefined" when I logged my data.

Comment: I thought I did. I copy/pasted it from the `react-router-dom` docs and tailored it closer to your code, and I included a link to that section. I've updated my answer to include a link to a running codesandbox. If you're seeing "undefined" when trying to access the `location.state` I mentioned to use the guard pattern to ensure the object property path is defined to the state value you need.

Comment: Can you not pass class instances into useNavigate's state? My private members are all lost when I do so?

Comment: @sayandcode I might need to see a [mcve] to help answer that question. Do you mind creating a new SO post for this question and relevant code? If you do feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look when available.

Comment: @DrewReese - I have deleted the comment. I tried to mean that, the guide for react router dom may help with solution in this context and also, I am struggling to pass a state as props from immediate parent to a child in react. I have searched a lot of SO solutions.. but couldn't get an idea. I want to pass a props through `<Link>` to a child. `props.location.state` is throwing an error. I am using react router dom v.6.3

Comment: @CommonMan In RRDv6 there are not any route props like there were in v5. You should use the `useLocation` hook to access the `location` object. I'll make this distinction more overt in my answer.

Comment: Under router v6 you posted a code sandbox which is using react router dom v.5.1. Which is using `<Link component=` v6 no longer using it, it uses, `<Link element=`.

Comment: @CommonMan Woah.... that RRDv5 sandbox was old enough it wasn't organized into my stackoverflow directory. I've updated the RRDv5 sandbox code to be more current, and added a RRDv6 sandbox demo in that section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use path params option of `react-router-dom` .

**Example**

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Topic from '../topic'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/topic/:name" component={Topic} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

**Pass the params:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Topics extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Link to="/topic/someTopicName">Some Topic</Link>;
  }
}
```

**Access router params in the component**

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Topic(props) {
  return <h1>{props.match.params.name}</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can pass data to navigated component

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: '/home/userDetails',
    state: {infoId: info.id},
  }}
>
```

And access like this in navigated component

if it's class based component.

```
this.props.location.state
```

if it's functional component

```
props.location.state
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using function component in your react application. You can follow below steps

**Main page:**

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: '/your/path',
    state: { 
       data: "your data"
    },
  }}
>
```

**In your child page or page you wanted to route:**

use useLocation (version 5.+) hook

```
const emp = useLocation()

console.log(emp)
```

**Output**

```
{ 
   state: { 
       data: "your data" 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Pass the state:**
import { Link} from "react-router-dom";
<Link to="/home/userDetails"  state: { userDetails:'Name'} }>

**Received the state:**
import { useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
const location = useLocation();
const userDetails= location.state.userDetails;
```

Comment: does not work..