# React.JS pass state to link, props.location.state is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I am passing a state to the `Link` component and trying to access the state using `props.location.satate`. Unfortunately, the state is undefined. I have tried to send the state from the `to` attribute using the `pathname` and `state`, still undefined.

```js
<Route exact path="/private/orders" name="Orders" component={PrivateOrders} />
```

Private orders

```js
import React from 'react'

const PrivateOrders = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Orders</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PrivateOrders
```

Link

```js
<Link  
   to="private/orders"
   state={{
      x: "y",
      y: "y",
      z: "y",
      i: "y",
   >
      <CButton color="primary">Order Now</CButton>
</Link>
```

result

```js
location: {pathname: '/private/orders', search: '', hash: '', state: undefined, key: 'lt9bpr'}
```

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864720/react-router-pass-props-to-handler-component ?

Comment: no, I want to send the state using the `Link` component

Comment: You appear to mixing up the component APIs, can you confirm which version of `react-router-dom` you have installed? From your project directory run `npm list react-router-dom`.

Comment: @DrewReese ` "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",`

Comment: I see. Follow the "Using react-router-dom v5" link instructions from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701168/8690857).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass routeProps in Route like this.

<Route exact path="/private/orders" name="Orders" component={(routeProps) => <PrivateOrders {...routeProps} />} />

Comment: same undefined state, it should be {...routeProps}

Comment: The `component` prop of a `Route`is supposed to take a component reference, not an anonymous React function. Use the `render` prop for this. See https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component