# React router 6 parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

actually, I have 2 questions.

1. How can I pass multiple parameters to a route
2. I'm getting undefined with this code; how can I receive my parameters.

```
const { name, family } = useParams();
```

I searched for my problem and most answers here are for class components and react router `v5`. so they didn't work for me.

I have a button, and when I click on it, the `useNavigate` function runs like this:

```
onClick={() => {
    HandleFetchListServiceConfer();
    navigate({
      pathname: "/SetServiceConfer",
      search: `${name}&${family}`,
    });
  }}
```

as you can see I add `name` and `family` to my route. but when I'm going to receive it in my `useParams`. it doesn't work. it return an empty object.

and about my first question. by ***adding multiple parameters***, I meant when you don't use `useNavigate` and you want to pass parameters in Route.

I tried something like this:

```
<Route
  path="/SetServiceConfer/:name/:family"
  element={<ListServiceConfer />}
/>
```

it destroys entire path. I got `not matching routes found`

The answer linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701050/how-to-pass-data-from-a-page-to-another-page-using-react-router) is unrelated. I get `undefined` with this answer.

Comment: Search is when you add `?name=something&family=something` you are using params, not search.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski how can I do it in right way? I didn't know that they were different.