# REACT NATIVE can't pass location.state in a CLASS COMPONENT using react-router-native anymore (TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined)

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-router-native

I need to pass data forward to another component via `<Link>` from the `react-router-native` library. This worked a couple of months ago, then I upgraded RN and all of the packages that I use and it's no longer working.
I found an answer which I thought related to my problem on Stack Overflow that involved changing the syntax of the props in my `<Link>` from:

```
to={{ pathname: "/search-method/", state: { ingreds: ingreds, more_needed: true } }}
```

to:

```
to="/search-method/" state={{ ingreds: ingreds, more_needed: true }}
```

Changing this syntax fixed the initial problem but when the next component loaded it couldn't retrieve the state data as it had before. Here's the relevant code from the next component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log("Search method mounted")
  var ingreds = this.props.location.state.ingreds
  var more_needed = this.props.location.state.more_needed
  var no_more_needed = this.props.location.state.no_more_needed
  var initial = this.props.location.state.initial_data
  if (initial !== undefined) {
    this.setState({
      initialData: initial,
      ingredients_rough: ingreds,
      moreNeeded: more_needed
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      ingredients_rough: ingreds,
      moreNeeded: more_needed
    })
  }
}
```

and the error points to the line `var ingreds = this.props.location.` < this full stop specifically, giving an error message, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined ".

Googling only seems to return results relating to react.js and react-router-dom, I can't find any answers as to why this is no longer working for React Native, in the package I'm using which worked fine before upgrading everything. Here's what I'm importing:

```
import { NativeRouter, Route, Link, Redirect } from "react-router-native";
```

Thanks in advance if you can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data from a page to another page using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701050/how-to-pass-data-from-a-page-to-another-page-using-react-router)

Comment: Yes, thank you. Lots of options on there. Only they all seem to use the react-router-dom library but I'm using react-router-native. I'm hoping to understand why it's suddenly stopped working and how I can alter my code to make it work again.

Comment: It's all basically the same code. `react-router` is the base repo and the others are just re-exporting it and adding in what is different/unique to the environment, i.e. `react-router-dom` and `react-router-native` share a common core.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know that, thank you for shedding some light on how they link.

Comment: Still working on this - my app uses class components so working with hooks is harder. It's a large app so I don't have time to restructure everything into functional components. If anybody knows a way in which to use react-router-native location.state with class components as we were able to before I'd appreciate advice!

Comment: Does my answer [here](/a/59701168/8690857) with regards to using `react-router@6` and class components, specifically the last section tagged "But I'm using a React class component" to create a custom `withRouter` HOC, help?

Comment: I tried it but it won't export here:
........................................... 

 "SyntaxError: "...\components\start.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (716:29)

  714 | });
  715 |
> 716 | export { HomePage, withRouter(SearchMethod), TimeAndType };
      |                              ^
  717 |

...........................................
 Exports fine on another file with the export default syntax.

Comment: You are exporting *named* exports. Try either `const DecoratedSearchMethod = withRouter(SearchMethod);` and `export { HomePage, DecoratedSearchMethod as SearchMethod, TimeAndType };`, or maybe directly `export { HomePage, withRouter(SearchMethod) as SearchMethod, TimeAndType };`.

Comment: The `<route>` in my `App.js` won't accept `const DecoratedSearchMethod = withRouter(SearchMethod);` as its element prop. The error says `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`

Comment: (I kept `SearchMethod` in there as the element name. I exported the named element as `DecoratedSearchMethod as SearchMethod` in its file as you suggested. Maybe it doesn't like that it's not a function anymore? Won't work as `withRouter(SearchMethod) as SearchMethod`, just points to the first bracket and says that it expected a comma.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-hill-69esrg?file=/src/start.js). It won't actually compile anymore but here's my code.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this was an Expo project. You might have better luck providing a demo via an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/). The renaming of the export appears to work with the first method I mentioned though. Here's a [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-cant-pass-location-state-in-a-class-component-using-react-router-n-idkg9s?file=/src/start.js:29832-29961) of your sandbox, it *mostly* compiles but falls over when it hits the expo specific code.

Comment: Yeah I still get this Error: `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.`   
Thanks anyway for taking the time to help.

Comment: (When I run it in my Emulator)

Comment: Just FYI I'm pointing out that *syntactically* the first method is correct, ***but*** if there is another issue in that file that prevents the file from compiling, then the components will fail to be exported. This might be what you are seeing.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for helping me to fix this specific syntax mistake.