# Navigation when clicking on an svg (using react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, react-router, jsx

I have an SVG Map which I have setup like this (I will skip a lot of the map out as it's mostly fills and quite large)

```
import React from "react";

function Map() {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="534.753"
      height="530.193"
      version="1"
      xmlSpace="preserve"
      role="img"
    >
      ...
      ...
      ...
      <path fill="#c1c9cc"
        ...
        id="Manhattan"
      >
      </path>
    </svg>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

And in my App.js I render the `Map` by

```
import Map2 from "./components/Map";
```

and then

```
<Map />
```

All is good.  My map is shown and with some CSS I can highlight areas.  All good.

My question comes now as to how to handle a click? What I'd like is to click on the map and it loads another page and that page will display a different title based on a prop the click passes.

I've been reading up and all I can find is using standard `<a>` tags - nothing about how to do this with an SVG.

I appreciate this post is quite "wordy" - but hoping for some better search terms that I can narrow things down with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle clicks to effect a navigation action then you have a couple options:

1. Update the `Map` component to take an `onClick` handler as a prop and attach it to a DOM element.

   ```
   import React from "react";

   function Map({ onClick }) {
     return (
       <svg
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="534.753"
         height="530.193"
         version="1"
         xmlSpace="preserve"
         role="img"
         onClick={onClick}
       >
         ...
       </svg>
     );
   }

   export default Map;
   ```

   ```
   import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
   import Map2 from "./components/Map";

   ...

   const navigate = useNavigate();

   ...

   <Map onClick={navigate.bind(null, "/foo")} />
   ```

   Pros:

   - `onClick` handler can do anything.

   Cons:

   - More to implement, requires a code change.
   - Not as accessible. For example, if linking to another page then interactive element needs appropriate accessibility role, keyboard handlers, ARIA, etc. These would be additional props/attributes to pass through.
2. Wrap the `Map` component in a `Link` (*or `NavLink`*) component.

   ```
   import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
   import Map2 from "./components/Map";

   ...

   <Link to="/foo">
     <Map />
   </Link>
   ```

   Pros:

   - Easier to implement and doesn't require a code change.
   - Has all the appropriate accessibility roles/attributes since they are handled by the `Link`

   Cons:

   - Is less versatile than using an `onClick` prop, only navigates.

### Demo

[image: Edit navigation-when-clicking-on-an-svg-using-react]

If you want a mix of the two, the accessibility of the `Link` and the versatility of an `onClick` handler then use a `Link` and add the `onClick` handler there if you need to issue other "side-effects"`.

```
<Link to="/foo" onClick={handleMapClick}>
  <Map />
</Link>
```

If you need to pass data from this component to the target route then you will pass state via the `navigate` function or the `Link` component. See my answer on [How to pass data from a page to another page using React-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701168/8690857) for specific details.

Comment: thank you - I will try these, that's given me something to think about!

Comment: I tried adding this to my app.js

```
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Link to={<Dashboard />}>
            <Map2 />
          </Link>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

And then the <Dashboard> is just a 

```
function Dashboard(props) {
  return <div>Here I am</div>;
}

export default Dashboard;
```

But I get a "react-refresh-runtime.development.js:232 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

I thought this would work (though I still would need to pass an Id in of the clicked area,

Comment: @Joseph Navigation works without issue here in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/navigation-when-clicking-on-an-svg-using-react-jv7fwn). `<Dashboard />` isn't a valid target path value, the `to` prop takes a string or `Path` object value, not JSX.

Comment: @Joseph Have you got the code working on your end yet?

Comment: I decided to go a different direction with it - removed the SVG - I am still playing about and may end up coming back

Comment: @Joseph Ok, no worries. However, has this answer sufficiently addressed/resolved your posted question/issue?