# I want to display user data if he entered the correct login info , but not getting expected results , I'm using react , java with tailwind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

my login with jpa api for backend connectivity to get correct info if user log into system , and show user data into dashboard if user entered correct log in info

```
const Login = () => {
  const [loginData, setLoginData] = useState({
    email: " ",
    password: " ",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById("passwordInput").value = "";
  }, []);
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState("");
  const [userState, setUser] = useState(null);

  const history = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const { state } = location;
  const { user } = state || {};

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setLoginData({
      ...loginData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/api/login", loginData)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setUser(response.data);
        history("/Student-Form/dashboard", { state: { user: response.data } });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
          setNotification(
            "Login failed with status code:" + error.response.status
          );

          if (error.response.status === 401) {
            setNotification("Invalid Password or User Not Found");
          } else {
            // ehllo
          }
        } else if (error.request) {
          setNotification("No response received");
        } else {
          setNotification("Error setting up the request:", error.message);
        }
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{notification}</div>
      <NavLink
        type="button"
        to="/Student-Form/all-students"
      >
        All
      </NavLink>
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <div className="mb-4">
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={loginData.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="email"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-6">
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={loginData.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="password"
            id="passwordInput"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button
            type="submit"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
          {user && <DashBoard user={user} />}
          <NavLink
            type="button"
            to="/Student-Form/registration"
          >
            Regitration
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

and here is my Dashboard Compo and i want to get user info here if user login , the user prop is coming from login Compo

```
  const DashBoard = (props) => {
  if (!props.location) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  const { user } = props.location.state;
  console.log("Received user prop:", user);

  console.log("Received user prop:", user);

  if (!user) {
    console.error("Invalid or incomplete user information:", user);
    return <div>Error: Invalid or incomplete user information</div>;
  }
  const { id, studentName, fatherName } = user;

  return (
    <div >
      <div >
        <div>
          <img
            src={""}
            alt="Profile Picture" />
          <p className="text-gray-500">Id: {id}</p>
          <h1 >Student Name: {studentName}</h1>
          <p>Father Name: {fatherName}</p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h2>User Information</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-6">
          <h2>Change Password</h2>
          {/* ... */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and my error i entering correct login info

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA0EG.png)

And here is my router setup

App.js

```
import { NavLink, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
      <Outlet />
      <NavLink to="/Student-Form">Login</NavLink> <br />
      <NavLink to="/Student-Form/registration">Regitration</NavLink> <br />
      <NavLink to="/Student-Form/all-students">Student List</NavLink> <br />
      <NavLink to="/Student-Form/dashboard">Dashboard</NavLink>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and my main.js

```
 const router = createBrowserRouter([
      {
        path: "Student-Form",
        element: <App />,
        children: [
          {
            path: "/Student-Form/",
            element: <Login />,
          },
          {
            path: "/Student-Form/registration",
            element: <StudentRegistration />,
          },
          {
            path: "/Student-Form/all-students",
            element: <StudentList />,
          },
          {
            path: "/Student-Form/dashboard",
            element: <DashBoard />,
          },
        ],
      },
    ]);
    
    ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    );
```

Comment: Where is `handleSubmit` declared and used? What component is the `user` state declared in? Why are you rendering more than one `Dashboard` component? I suspect you *are* setting the `user` state and navigating to `"/dashboard"`, but the `Dashboard` component rendered on that route isn't passed any `user` prop, so `user` is undefined within the component "instance". Can you [edit] to clarify the issue in greater detail and include a more complete [mcve] along with exact reproduction steps?

Comment: okay sir , I will

Comment: please watch again and give me some sugggestion

Comment: If you ***don't*** navigate to `"/dashboard"` then `Login` will likely remain mounted and the `{user && <DashBoard user={user} />}` will allow `Dashboard` to be rendered and the `user` state passed to it as props. If this isn't what you want then we still need to see a more complete [mcve]. I recall your post previously included the routes and there was a `<Route path="dashboard" element=<Dashboard />} />` route where there was no `user` prop passed. Is ***this*** the `Dashboard` component you would like to pass the `user` data to?

Comment: if I don't navigate then how I can get user details in Dashboard?

Comment: Like I said, `Login` is already rendering a `Dashboard` component and passing `user` to it, so as long as you are not navigating away from the route that is rendering `Login`, the `Dashboard` will render. But also like I said, this doesn't seem to be the behavior you actually want, and if so, we need a more complete [mcve]. I suspect you don't need the `user` state at all and can simply pass user data in route state when navigating to `"/dashboard"`. Again though, we need a more complete [mcve] and details/clarity to really understand what you are trying to do overall.

Comment: Can you explain how can I pass user data in route state when navigating to "/dashboard"  , and I'm new in programming sir

Comment: I will add my router setup

Comment: Does this answer help explain how to pass the user data to the dashboard route? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701168/8690857 If you still need a bit of help I can provide more details if/when this post reopens.

Comment: I did "history("/Student-Form/dashboard", { state: { user: response.data } }); " and const { user } = props.location.state; still data not going

Comment: Check the link again for how to access the passed data in the receiving component. Hint: chances are `props` is undefined, use the `useLocation` hook. E.g. `const { state } = useLocation();`, `const { user } = state || {};`.

Comment: where i should use this useLocation hook ? In Login Compo or Dashboard?

Comment: In the component rendered on the route you are navigating to. If `Dashboard` is rendered on `"/dashboard"`, then that is the component that should attempt reading `location.state`.

Comment: not getting result as expected , sir check again my post i posted updated code of proejct

Comment: You are still trying to read `props` in `DashBoard` but clearly no props are passed to `Dashboard`, e.g `element: <DashBoard />` in the router.

Comment: All done sir , just got expected results, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

The `Dashboard` component isn't passed any props, this should hopefully be clear by examining where and how it is rendered.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "Student-Form",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/Student-Form/",
        element: <Login />,
      },
      {
        path: "/Student-Form/registration",
        element: <StudentRegistration />,
      },
      {
        path: "/Student-Form/all-students",
        element: <StudentList />,
      },
      {
        path: "/Student-Form/dashboard",
        element: <DashBoard />, // <-- no props passed here
      },
    ],
  },
]);
    
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

## Solution

- Rename `history` to `navigate` to keep the function name consistent with official documentation and usage.
- Pass the `user` data directly in route state when effecting the navigation action.
- Remove `{user && <DashBoard user={user} />}` from the `Login` component since `Dashboard` is rendered on a route, separately.
- `Dashboard` uses the `useLocation` hook to access the passed route state.

Login

```
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [loginData, setLoginData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setLoginData(loginData => ({
      ...loginData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/api/login", loginData)
      .then((response) => {
        navigate("/Student-Form/dashboard", { state: { user: response.data } });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
          setNotification(
            "Login failed with status code:" + error.response.status
          );

          if (error.response.status === 401) {
            setNotification("Invalid Password or User Not Found");
          } else {
            // ehllo
          }
        } else if (error.request) {
          setNotification("No response received");
        } else {
          setNotification("Error setting up the request:", error.message);
        }
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{notification}</div>
      <NavLink
        type="button"
        to="/Student-Form/all-students"
      >
        All
      </NavLink>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={loginData.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="email"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-6">
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={loginData.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="password"
            id="passwordInput"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
          <NavLink
            type="button"
            to="/Student-Form/registration"
          >
            Registration
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Dashboard

```
const DashBoard = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { user } = state || {};

  if (!user) {
    console.error("Invalid or incomplete user information:", user);
    return <div>Error: Invalid or incomplete user information</div>;
  }

  const { id, studentName, fatherName } = user;

  return (
    <div >
      <div >
        <div>
          <img
            src={""}
            alt="Profile Picture" />
          <p className="text-gray-500">Id: {id}</p>
          <h1 >Student Name: {studentName}</h1>
          <p>Father Name: {fatherName}</p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h2>User Information</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-6">
          <h2>Change Password</h2>
          {/* ... */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Nested routes can be built/referenced *relative* to their parent route, so the `router` can be written a bit more succinctly.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "Student-Form",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Login /> },
      { path: "registration", element: <StudentRegistration /> },
      { path: "all-students", element: <StudentList /> },
      { path: "dashboard", element: <DashBoard /> },
    ],
  },
]);
```