# component doesnt shown in nest react routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

this is my code i create routing for my components like this

```
<Routes >
  <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/login" replace />} />
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Layout component={Dashboard} />} />
  <Route path="/sale" element={<BookDetails />}>
    <Route exact path="/sale/:bookId" element={<Layout component={BookhDetails} />} />
    <Route path="/sale/:bookId/salebooks" element={<Layout component={SaleBooks} />} />
    <Route path="/sale/:bookId/viewbooks" element={<Layout component={ViewBooks} />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes >
```

my problems

1. i want to show title for each book on the BookDetails component but title should not be shown in the url , so url for detail component willbe like this: /sale/:bookId

2.when in BookDetails component i click on link i want to go to salebooks component but after i click on link just url changes to /sale/:bookId /salebooks but it shows BooksDetails component!.
thankyou for your help.

**dashboar**: this link in dashboard goes to bookDetails component.

```
<Link to={`/sale/${book.id}`} onClick={() => navigate(`/sale/${book.id}`)}>
  <button type="submit" className="btn custome-btn purple-active-ghost w-100">
    {book.title}
  </button>
</Link>
```

**BookDetails:** this link will be goes to SaleBooks component.

```
<Link to={`/sale/${bookId}/salebooks`}>
  <button type="submit" className="btn custome-btn purple-active-ghost w-100">
     go to salebooks 
  </button>
</Link>
```

Comment: How are you wanting to get the book title to the `BookDetails` component? Does `BookDetails` need to be passed a "book" object that has all the relevant book data from the dashboard, or is there some global state/context that has the array of book data that can be searched?

Comment: @ DrewReese I used to be able to get the title like  bookId through the URL, but now I can't, and I have no idea what to do about it."

Comment: `BookDetails` should render an `Outlet` for the nested routes it wraps. Can you [edit] to include the current version of your `BookDetails` component?

Comment: @DrewReese i cant use `Outlet` in ` BookDetails` because i don't want to render ` `BookDetails` itself in nested routes .in the ` BookDetails` i just some `links ` that they route to the nested routes i define  for sale component

Comment: @DrewReese my second problem solved with replacing this line: `<Route path="/sale/:bookId" element={<Outlet />}>` thanks for mentioning `Outlet`.

Comment: You can remove `element={<Outlet />}` on that route since `Route` will render an `Outlet` by default if not specified. For the first problem, how do you want to access book data in the details page? Are you open to any suggestion that gets the book data, e.g. title, there for the details? Are you using the same `Dashboard` component from your first post that maps a `books` array to render the details links?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest updating the `Layout` component to be a route layout component that renders an `Outlet` for the nested routes it renders, and then provide the `books` array out on the outlet context for the nested routes to consume. This allows the more deeply nested routes to fetch a specific book's details by the `bookId` route path parameter.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export const BooksLayout = () => {
  ...any business logic the layout had

  return (
    <>
      ...any common UI the layout had

      {/* Render Outlet for nested routes and provide books array */}
      <Outlet context={{ books }} />

      ...any common UI the layout had
    </>
  );
};
```

```
<Routes >
  <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/login" replace />} />
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route element={<BooksLayout />}>
    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
    <Route path="/sale/:bookId">
      <Route index element={<BookDetails />} />          // "/sale/:bookId"
      <Route path="salebooks" element={<SaleBooks />} /> // "/sale/:bookId/salebooks"
      <Route path="viewbooks" element={<ViewBooks />} /> // "/sale/:bookId/viewbooks"
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

Consumers use the [`useOutletContext`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context) hook to access the provided `books` array from the outlet context provider.

Dashboard

```
import { Link, useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';
...

const { books } = useOutletContext();

...

{books.map((book) => (
  <div className="col" key={book.id}>
    <div className="card h-100">
      <div className="card-img-top pb-5 mb-5">
    </div>
    <div className="card-body">
      <Link to={`/sale/${book.id}`}>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="btn custome-btn purple-active-ghost w-100"
        >
          {book.title}
        </button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  </div>
)}
```

BookDetails

```
import { Link, useOutletContext, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
...

const { bookId } = useParams();
const { books } = useOutletContext();
const book = books.find(book => book.id === bookId);

...

// if book exists, access all book object properties, e.g. id, title, and more

<Link to={`/sale/${book.id}/salebooks`}>
  <button
    type="submit"
    className="btn custome-btn purple-active-ghost w-100"
  >
    go to {book.title} salebooks 
  </button>
</Link>
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer but i have problem :book is undefined in the `BookDetails`, Are there simpler solutions? without using context?

Comment: @Negin Can you clarify what ":book" in the `BookDetails` component you are referring to? Are you referring to `book` from `const book = books.find(book => book.id === bookId);`? If so, can you clarify what type of value `book.id` is? I assumed `book.id` is a string type, so the comparison is type-safe, but if the book ids are just numbers then you'll need to convert `book.id` so you can use a type-safe comparison. It's trivial with the String constructor, e.g. `const book = books.find(book => String(book.id) === bookId);`, so you can use a string-to-string strict equality test.

Comment: yes i mean `const book = books.find(book => book.id === bookId);` , & book.id is a string .

Comment: thankyou for your help i found this solution & it works for now. 
in dashboard :
`
const handlebookClick = (book) => {
  navigate(`/sale/${book.id}`, { state: { title: book.title } });
};
<button onClick={() => handlebookClick(book)}>
  {book.title}
</button>
`
in detail:
`
const location = useLocation();
const title = location.state?.title; // then i can use title
`

Comment: @Negin Yes, passing data in route state is also a way to [pass data from one page to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701168/8690857). I believe if you reload the page that the state is reset, so the title may become undefined. Using the outlet context allows the data to effectively always exist and be available to the descendent components.